# Issue with pixel_array using pydicom on python 3.x

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, pydicom

I'm using `pydicom` (installed with `pip3`, on python 3.7, using `Idle`) and I need to access `pixel_array` values.

I just copy-paste the example provided into [the documentation](https://pydicom.github.io/pydicom/stable/auto_examples/input_output/plot_read_dicom.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-input-output-plot-read-dicom-py) and this leads to two errors:

- first is about the `get_testdata_files` operation, which is not working because

  ```
  Python 3.7.3 (v3.7.3:ef4ec6ed12, Mar 25 2019, 22:22:05) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
  Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information.
  >>> 
  ==================== RESTART: D:\OneDrive\Desktop\test.py ====================
  None
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "D:\OneDrive\Desktop\test.py", line 8, in <module>
      filename = get_testdata_files("bmode.dcm")[0]
  IndexError: list index out of range
  ```

I have solved this not using this operation.

- second is about the `pixel_array` and I'm not so able to decode what is wrong, but it seems like the `pixel_array` is not populated. However I'm able to access other fields in the dataset and the file can be displayed (using `ImageJ` for example).

  ```
  ==================== RESTART: D:\OneDrive\Desktop\test.py ====================
  None

  Filename.........: bmode.dcm
  Storage type.....: 1.2.840.10008.5.1.4.1.1.3.1

  Patient's name...: Femoral trombenarterectomy, Case Report:
  Patient id.......: Case Report 1
  Modality.........: US
  Study Date.......: 20110824
  Image size.......: 768 x 1024, 27472108 bytes
  Slice location...: (missing)
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\OneDrive\Desktop\test.py", line 38, in <module>
       plt.imshow(dataset.pixel_array, cmap=plt.cm.bone)
  File "C:\Users\marcl\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pydicom\dataset.py", line 949, in pixel_array
       self.convert_pixel_data()
  File "C:\Users\marcl\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pydicom\dataset.py", line 895, in convert_pixel_data
       raise last_exception
  File "C:\Users\marcl\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pydicom\dataset.py", line 863, in convert_pixel_data
  arr = handler.get_pixeldata(self)
   File "C:\Users\marcl\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pydicom\pixel_data_handlers\pillow_handler.py", line 188, in get_pixeldata
  UncompressedPixelData.extend(decompressed_image.tobytes())
  File "C:\Users\marcl\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 746, in tobytes
  self.load()
  File "C:\Users\marcl\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\PIL\ImageFile.py", line 261, in load
  raise_ioerror(err_code)
  File "C:\Users\marcl\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\PIL\ImageFile.py", line 58, in raise_ioerror
  raise IOError(message + " when reading image file")
  ```

  OSError: broken data stream when reading image file

Here is my code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import sys
import pydicom
import numpy
from pydicom.data import get_testdata_files

print(__doc__)
#filename = get_testdata_files("bmode.dcm")[0]
filename = "bmode.dcm"
dataset = pydicom.dcmread(filename)

# Normal mode:
print()
print("Filename.........:", filename)
print("Storage type.....:", dataset.SOPClassUID)
print()

pat_name = dataset.PatientName
display_name = pat_name.family_name + ", " + pat_name.given_name
print("Patient's name...:", display_name)
print("Patient id.......:", dataset.PatientID)
print("Modality.........:", dataset.Modality)
print("Study Date.......:", dataset.StudyDate)

if 'PixelData' in dataset:
    rows = int(dataset.Rows)
    cols = int(dataset.Columns)
    print("Image size.......: {rows:d} x {cols:d}, {size:d} bytes".format(
        rows=rows, cols=cols, size=len(dataset.PixelData)))
    if 'PixelSpacing' in dataset:
        print("Pixel spacing....:", dataset.PixelSpacing)


# use .get() if not sure the item exists, and want a default value if missing
print("Slice location...:", dataset.get('SliceLocation', "(missing)"))

# plot the image using matplotlib
plt.imshow(dataset.pixel_array, cmap=plt.cm.bone)
plt.show()
```

Could you help me to solve these two errors and access pixel_array values?
Don't hesitate to give me some advices /remarks/...

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi Marc welcome to SO!

Your first error means that the `get_testdata_files` returns an empty list, so your file is not found. Have a look at [the pydicom source](https://github.com/pydicom/pydicom/blob/c98efd8e39c0ecb0faf46e6e79f84d5c437dec97/pydicom/data/data_manager.py#L43), it shows that a search is performed in `[DATA_ROOT]/test_files`. Is your file located in that path?

Your second error is related to PIL and that can be quite difficult to debug and fix. First try to read the `pixel_array` from a dataset created from one of the [supplied test files](https://github.com/pydicom/pydicom/tree/master/pydicom/data/test_files). If that works, your problem is probably that PIL cannot handle the specific encoding of your image data. You want to [install and use GDCM](https://github.com/malaterre/GDCM) instead of PIL to see if that solves the problem. Another user has had a [similar issue](https://github.com/pydicom/pydicom/issues/776) as you, GDCM solved the problem. It can be a bit of a headache to get working unfortunately. Or [have a look at this page](https://pydicom.github.io/pydicom/stable/viewing_images.html), it shows some other alternatives on viewing the image data.

Comment: Thank You so much! You are right on the first issue. I solved the second in correcting the metadata ; in these, the number of frames was 16 while the PixelData contains only 1 frame... So, it works now ;-)